# Hauppage WinTV USB 40001

Tags: linux, video, v4l

I have tried, unsuccessfully, to hook up my (very old) video capture device. I have tried making it work with `tvtime`, but to no avail. I've tried sending messages to th e dsitribution list but I've had no replies yet (no wonder, it was today, but I've decided to take a more proactive apprach :). Maybe some of you have had the same issue? Here's the error:

```
Your capture card driver: USBVision [Hauppauge WinTV USB (NTSC M/N)/usb-
0000:00:1d.0-1.8/
does not support full size studio-quality images required by tvtime.
This is true for many low-quality webcams.  Please select a
different video device for tvtime to use with the command line
option --device.
```

Any ideas?